# Properly exploit parallelism when building a map of expensive keys?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm writing a toy implementation of a [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) in Haskell. The main datastructure is a strict `Map h c`, containing a large amount of pairs, generated from random values `c`:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import System.Random

table :: (RandomGen g, Random c) => Int -> g -> Map h c
table n = M.fromList . map (\c -> (chain c, c)) . take n . randoms
```

where `chain` is very expensive to compute. The part that dominates the computation time is embarrassingly parallel, so I would expect to get a quasi-linear speedup in the number of cores if it runs in parallel.

However, I would like the computed pairs to be added to the table straight away, rather than accumulated in a list in memory. It should be noted that collisions may occur, and in that case, the redundant chains should be dropped as soon as possible. Heap profiling confirms that this is the case.

I've found `parMap` from `Control.Parallel.Strategies`, and tried to apply it to my table-building function:

```
table n = M.fromList . parMap (evalTuple2 rseq rseq) (\c -> (chain c, c)) . take n . randoms
```

but, running with `-N`, I get to 1.3 core usage at best. Heap profiling indicates, at least, that the intermediate list does not reside in memory, but '-s' also reports 0 sparks created. How is this possible with my usage of `parMap` ? What is the proper way to do this ?

*EDIT*: `chain` is defined as:

```
chain :: (c -> h) -> [h -> c] -> c -> h
chain h = h . flip (foldl' (flip (.h)))
```

where `(c -> h)` is the target hash function, from cleartext to hash, 
and `[h -> c]` is a family of reducer functions. I want the implementation to stay generic over `c` and `h`, but for benchmarking I use strict bytestrings for both.

Comment: What version of `parallel` are you using? Sufficiently old versions have some pretty significant problems.

Comment: @dfeuer parallel-3.2.2.0, unfortunately

Comment: Hrmmmm.... What `-N` argument are you using?

Comment: @dfeuer I tried -N4 and -N8, both give more or less the same result (below 2 cores usage)

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/lehins/haskell-scheduler I wrote it specifically for use cases like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with. Let me know how the benchmarks work out:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack --resolver lts-14.1 script --optimize
  --package scheduler
  --package containers
  --package random
  --package splitmix
  --package deepseq
-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Scheduler
import Data.Foldable as F
import Data.IORef
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Data.Map.Strict as M
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Random as R
import System.Random.SplitMix


-- for simplicity
chain :: Show a => a -> String
chain = show

makeTable :: Int -> SMGen -> (SMGen, M.Map String Int)
makeTable = go M.empty
  where go !acc i gen
          | i > 0 =
            let (c, gen') = R.random gen
            in go (M.insert (chain c) c acc) (i - 1) gen'
          | otherwise = (gen,  acc)

makeTablePar :: Int -> SMGen -> IO (M.Map String Int)
makeTablePar n0 gen0 = do
  let gens = unfoldr (Just . splitSMGen) gen0
  gensState <- initWorkerStates Par (\(WorkerId wid) -> newIORef (gens !! wid))
  tables <-
    withSchedulerWS gensState $ \scheduler -> do
      let k = numWorkers (unwrapSchedulerWS scheduler)
          (q, r) = n0 `quotRem` k
      forM_ ((if r == 0 then [] else [r]) ++ replicate k q) $ \n ->
        scheduleWorkState scheduler $ \genRef -> do
          gen <- readIORef genRef
          let (gen', table) = makeTable n gen
          writeIORef genRef gen'
          table `deepseq` pure table
  pure $ F.foldl' M.union M.empty tables

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [n] <- fmap read <$> getArgs
  gen <- initSMGen
  print =<< makeTablePar n gen
```

Few notes on implementation:

- Don't use generator from `random`, it is hella slow, `splitmix` is x200 faster
- In `makeTable`, if you want duplicate results to be discarded right away, then manual loop or unfold is required. But since we need the generator returned, I opted for the manual loop.
- In order to minimize synchronization between threads, independent maps will be built up per thread, and at the end duplicates get removed, when resulting maps are merged together.

Comment: I think you can use `union` rather than `merge` here. I like `merge` (I wrote it), but I tend to prefer simpler tools when they apply. Once you get into `differenceWith`, yeah, it makes sense to just jump for `merge` rather than learning some weird extra API.

Comment: I'll have a look and get back to you, thank you very much. Still, it would be a bit disheartening if there was no way to achieve this without falling back to `IO` and explicit concurrency.

Comment: @dfeuer I remember there was a function like `union`, but somehow it's name skipped my mind, thanks for the suggestion. Good job on the merge interface, it's mighty handy!
@b0fh You are welcome. Unfortunately if you want good performance from parallelization in Haskell dropping to IO is often necessary. In the above solution because of non-determinism you can't even pretend that it is a pure computation with unsafePerformIO.

Comment: @b0fh, you should definitely try `monad-par` before dropping all the way to `IO`. But even that seems like overkill here, IMO. If the problem is that the PRNG is too slow, you can either use a faster one or recursively split a random seed so you can distribute the work of generating pseudorandom numbers across the threads that need them. Or both.

Comment: @dfeuer I have a strong argument against `monad-par`. The fact that it is pure, doesn't make it better, especially since it doesn't give you the desired improvement in performance. See the benchmarks here: https://github.com/lehins/haskell-scheduler#benchmarks

Comment: @b0fh I certainly do not discourage you from trying `monad-par`, in fact, it would be great if you could compare performance of the suggested solution with some other that uses `monad-par` or any approach that solves this problem.

Comment: Any performance problems with `monad-par` can probably be resolved by improving its schedulers or implementing a new one. You should offer your scheduling prowess to Simon Marlow!

Comment: @dfeuer the problem is not the PRNG, actually; a chain is typically long of thousands of hashes, and time profiling tells me less than 2% of time is being spent in the slow StdGen. It spends 70% of its itme in the hash function itself, which I'm quite happy about, and 25% in my reducer (that provides quasi-uniform distribution for the cleartext, so is a bit expensive)